# Definition of basic reject, basic ack and basic nack and why when they should be used?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ. I am struggling to understand meaning of following functions. Can someone explain or give link to help me understand following functions:

```cs
RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs e = (RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
    
Model.BasicReject(e.DeliveryTag, false);
Model.BasicReject(e.DeliveryTag, true);
    
Model.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
Model.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
    
Model.BasicNack(e.DeliveryTag, true, true);
Model.BasicNack(e.DeliveryTag, false, false);
```

I read `BasicAck/BasicNack` rejects multiple messages. Is there any use of using Ack/Nack with multiple flag set as false?

After publishing to dead letter, we should reject it or used `BasicNack`? Should we requeue the message?

Comment: Tried to read [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) ?

Comment: I did. I have editted the question with my understanding and doubts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: "I read BasicAck/BasicNack rejects multiple messages. Is there any use of using Ack/Nack with multiple flag set as false?"

A: If you have a prefetch of 1 then no. If you have a prefetch that is higher, and it is not complex for you to do multiple acknowledgement, then go for it. Performance is better with multiple acknowledgement. But be careful not to acknowledge a delivery tag lower than you have previously acknowledged.

Q: "After publishing to dead letter, we should reject it or used BasicNack? Should we requeue the message?"

A: Use BasicNack with requeue=false, this will send it to the dead letter exchange if the queue has one configured. If you don't want a dead letter exchange but want to forward failed messages to a different exchange, then Ack the message and publish to the other exchange.